# TYPO3: indexed_search and title tag

Tags: search, title, typo3

Is there a way to get a title tag in the search results of indexed_search?

Instead of

```
<a href="section/site.html">Text</a>
```

there should be

```
<a href="section/site.html" title="Text">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real solution but best I could do:

I think this won't be possible without changing the extension's PHP code. If you do so, copy the extension folder from the systext folder to your typo3conf/ext folder, otherwise you will get in trouble when updating Typo3.

indexed_search seems to have only hardcoded -Tags. You can check this by looking first at the actual HTML output (your search results). Then compare this with the HTML template used. If you have shell access to your server, a grep command might help to locate the correct template. Then try to find the marker. I suppose in your case it's ###TITLE###. Then you have to figure out how the marker is filled. Again a grep command for '###TITLE###' in the folder's extension might help you. Then you will see if the  tag is hardcoded or not and how you can change it.

Often the faster solution is to use the template object browser and to try to find a piece of TypoScript below plugin.indexed_search which could be responsible what you want to change.

Unfortunately in your case both didn't help. For some strange reason, '###TITLE###' isn't contained anywhere in the the indexed_search extension.

A very ugly workaround would be to use javascript or jquery to insert the attribute.